# Pass Querystring Data to External Site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am at a loss on something rather simple.  I have two .net sites hosted in IIS.

I would like to pass data from one site to another to allow single sign on to the other site.

Site A:
Response.Redirect("https://www.siteb.com?A=data");

Site B:
Request.QueryString["A"] is always null.

Any ideas on what I am missing??

Comment: Maybe `Request.QueryString["A"]` ? Your query parameter name is "A"

Comment: Sorry but that was a typo.

Comment: Request.QueryString["A"] is what I have

Comment: What happens when you take site A out of the equation, and just go to `https://www.siteb.com?A=data` in your browser?

Comment: That works fine, there seems to be an issue with the redirect from A to B

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  There was a URL Rewrite rule that was clearing out the querystring